# 403 when deploying symfony api on Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, api-platform.com

I'm tring to deploy a Symfony api on heroku but I got a "Forbiden to access this resource".

I have a Procfile which contain : `'web: heroku-php-apache2 public/'`

For my htaccess file :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    SetEnvIf Content-Type "(.*)" HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE=$1
    SetEnvIf Accept "(.*)" HTTP_ACCEPT=$1
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]
    
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Anyone had the same problem please ?

Comment: you are missing the authorization, what exactly you want to achieve with the auth parts in htaccess or did you just copy from elsewhere?

Comment: I read that on documentation ! Do you think that i should remove it ?